# Pandas.ExcelWriter KeyError when using writer.sheets method

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Please help, I don't know why this error is happening. I have used this code previously with no issues. I hope it's not something stupid. Always appreciate the help.

Versions:

python 3.6

pd 0.23.0

xlsxwriter 1.0.4

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/eclipse/dropins/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.2.0.201903251948/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Sheet1'
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: Have you named your `Sheet1` to something else?

Comment: @prp Yes. It appears the string doesn't matter.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the string is, you're trying to reference something that does not yet exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't create a Sheet 1.

from [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) there's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1') ***#this is where you create Sheet 1***

# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1'] ***#here is where you select it***
```

Comment: Thank you @mauve ! You are correct I need to use call to_excel first.

Answer (score 3):

you have to add a sheet to your excel file before using it as follow:

```
    excel_writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('f2.xlsx',mode ='w',engine='xlsxwriter')
    workbook  = excel_writer.book
    excel_writer.sheets={'Sheet1':workbook.add_worksheet()}
    worksheet = excel_writer.sheets['Sheet1']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Pandas, you should use the [.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) function. It'd be easier! :)

Comment: I agree, in this case I will be adding images and charts that to_excel does not support thanks